# Can I encapsulate WCF or Web API within an Ajax Server Control?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asmx, servercontrols

I'm pretty new to services within .NET and not too experienced with .NET in general, so please excuse my ignorance.

I've been tasked with implementing a self-contained login control which could be used within a number of applications.  I've done some browsing around and have made a little progress, but wondered if there might be a better way to go, before I go too far.

So far, I have an AJAX Server Control which includes a .asmx web service that is being called through AJAX.

I have concerns about the security of this solution and also understand that .asmx is no longer in favor due to the rise of WCF and Web API.  I've tried to find an example of WCF or web API being used in a similar manner, but haven't come across anything.  Is this possible?

I'm also thinking that maybe a better approach would be to have the Web API service run outside of the Control, but just have the control call it.

Is this even a secure way to manage authorization and authentication?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start  here: [Exposing WCF Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514961%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)